# InverseLaplaceTransform not working

Tags: fourier-analysis, inverse, integral-transforms

I am trying to find the Inverse Laplace transform of a function I previously obtained from a Laplace transform, but the result obtained does not agree with the initial function. Why is this happening?

```
LaplaceTransform[2 z^3 Coth[z] Csch[z]^2, z, s] // FullSimplify
InverseLaplaceTransform[%, s, z] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> -(48/(-2 + s)^4) + 3 PolyGamma[1, -1 + s/2] + 
>  1/8 s (12 PolyGamma[2, -1 + s/2] + s PolyGamma[3, -1 + s/2])
> -2 E^(2 z) z (3 + z (9 + 4 z) + 3 Coth[z] (1 + 2 z - z Coth[z]))
> ```

The last line does not agree with the initial function I was transforming: `2 z^3 Coth[z] Csch[z]^2`.

Comment: Have you tried substituting numerical values for `z` to verify that the expressions are not equivalent?

Comment: Yes, they are definitely different. You can plot those functions and check.

Comment: LaplaceTransform[TrigToExp[2 z^3* Coth[z] *Csch[z]^2] // Simplify, z, s] produces a big expression and InverseLaplace Transform fails with it, returning the input.

Comment: Which version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: @mikado; Version 12.0 under Windows 10 32-bit on 64-bit machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's seems a **BUG** in `InverseLaplaceTransform`.I checked in version **12.0** and **12.1**.
both occur.

If we try:

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[ s^2 PolyGamma[3, -1 + s/2], s, z](*Wrong Answer !!!*)
(* 0 *)
```

We can check and using identity for [PolyGamma](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma2/06/04/0012/) function:

```
func = FullSimplify[LaplaceTransform[2*z^3*Coth[z]*Csch[z]^2, z, s]] //
Expand
(*-(48/(-2 + s)^4) + 3 PolyGamma[1, -1 + s/2] + 
3/2 s PolyGamma[2, -1 + s/2] + 1/8 s^2 PolyGamma[3, -1 + s/2]*)

func1 = FullSimplify[
InverseLaplaceTransform[ func[[1 ;; 3]], s, z] + 
 Sum[1/8 InverseLaplaceTransform[s^2*6/(-1 + k + s/2)^4, s, 
    z], {k, 0, Infinity}], z > 0] // ExpToTrig // Simplify
(* 2 z^3 Coth[z] Csch[z]^2 *)
```

Result obtained does agree with the initial function.

**EDITED:**

**RE: [CASE:4392492] Bug in Mathematica 12.1 (InverseLaplaceTransform)**

It does appear that InverseLaplaceTransform is not behaving correctly/consistently. I have forwarded an issue report to our developers with the information you provided. I also included your contact information in my report.